# What is meaning of xhr.readystate===4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it right to say that the **AJAX** call has completed after `xhr.readystate===4`?
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) it says the state is `complete`. So what does this `complete` mean?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

An Ajax http request has 5 states as your reference documents:

```
0   UNSENT  open() has not been called yet.
1   OPENED  send() has been called.
2   HEADERS_RECEIVED    send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
3   LOADING Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
4   DONE    The operation is complete.
```

State 4 means that the request had been sent, the server had finished returning the response and the browser had finished downloading the response content.
So, it is right to say that the AJAX call has completed.

Comment: Once again, it is absolutely useless to use === for operands that are not ambiguous, such as 4. 4 could never be empty string, or null, or 0. 4 is 4...

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is correct.`xhr.readstate===4` means request finished and response is ready. You can refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) for details.

Here is small example:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
         alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
     }
 }
 xmlhttp.send(null);
```

The above script makes a GET request for the relative url "text.txt" (relative to the calling page) It provides the function, which checks the readyState property each time it's called and when it has the value 4 - meaning the load is complete, it displays the responseText to the user with an alert.

[Source](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html)

Comment: Your link doesn't work. But please avoid recommending w3schools.com if there's a better source, such as the link in the question itself.