# Javascript GET not getting entire json file

Tags: javascript, json, coordinate-systems

I have, what I would presume large, JSON file in which my javascript code is not pulling in all the data. I know this because in the Network tab of developer tools in FireFox states that it's receiving an end of data marker at like 57,301 but there are 528,342 lines of JSON in the file.

I tried to just fetch but I kept getting errors about 'await' needing to be used async but I'm not familiar with how asynchronous functions work. In my xmlhttp request I have async flag set to false. It was the only way that I could get it to work with the code I am running.

I'm pulling in json objects with lat, lon and altitude. My JSON is formatted as such:

```
{"points":[
{"lat": 0, "lon": 0},
.
.
.
{"lat": 0, "lon": 0}]}
```

My request is coded as such

```
function get_json_data(){
var data = [];
var response = new XMLHttpRequest();
response.onreadystatechange = function(){

     data_points = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     *** CONVERTING LAT/LON TO ARRAY AND PUTTING INTO DATA ***

});
response.open("GET", "http://url/path/to/json", false);
response.send();

return data;
}
```

It works fine with a JSON file that's not that large, probably 10,000 lines. How can I get this to work with a JSON file much much larger, 500,000+ lines?

Comment: Might be worth adding a readyState checker to your code, since the `onreadystatechange` handler is actually called 4 times... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30522680/5037905)

Comment: Also, if you can see the issue occur at the browser level, chances are the issue is with however you're hosting the JSON file, rather than with your client.

Comment: [Read the warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) about not using readyStateChanged with synchronous (what you are doing) requests

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the JSON size, I think things like this are better handled asynchronously since you are loading it from an external source (an API, the file system, ...). So I suggest you give `fetch()` another try. Sadly, jsbin and jsfiddle won't let me call external APIs due to security reasons so I can't make an interactive demo, but the code should look like this:

```
async function getData() {

    const response = await fetch('<url here>');
    const json = await response.json();

    // Do stuff with JSON

}

========== OR ==========

function getData() {

    fetch('<url here')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            doStuffWithData(data);
        });

}
```

Basically the Fetch API returns a response, which you need to do something with (e.g. check if the status is 200 OK, see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch). In your case you'll want to transform the response to a JSON object when you've made sure the request was successful, and then manipulate that JSON.

For very large files, it may be that you need to look into Streams. The Fetch API does support this it seems, see here for a usage example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Comment: I tried this and the functionality of async worked for me but I kept getting the same error about the json end of file too early

Comment: It could be that the file is too large to load into memory all at once. I think reading the file as a stream may help. I've edited my answer to include a reference.